# Finding a constant in probability function

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a probability function of a random variable $\ x $ set by : $$\ p_{x}(i)= c \cdot0.4^i \ \ \ \ , i=1,2,3 \dots$$ and I need to find c.
 now because  $\ \sum_{i} P\{X=x_i\} = 1 $
so according to the solutions sheet  $$\ 1=  p_x(i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty c \cdot 0.4^i = c \cdot\sum_{i=1}^\infty 0.4^{i} = c( \frac{1}{1-0.4} - 1) = c(\frac{2}{3})   = 1 \Rightarrow c=\frac{3}{2}$$

I don't understand why it is equal to  $\ c(\frac{1}{1-0.4} - 1) $ ??

I understand there's the identity $$\ \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = \frac{1}{1-x} $$

But where did the $\ - 1 $ came from??

Comment: From the fact that your series starts at $i=1$, not at $i=0$, hence one should substract $(0.4)^0=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $-1$ came from the geometric series formula being the sum from $i = 0$ to $\infty$ rather than in your probability function where the $i$ starts from $1$. That is,
$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = x^0 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty x^i = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty x^i.$$

Comment: Still not sure though.. You write $\ 1 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty x^i $ not $\ 1- \sum_{i=1}^\infty x^i  $

Comment: What you wanted to calculate was of the form $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^i$. We've just shown that $1 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty x^i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i$. Thus,  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i - 1 = \frac{1}{1-x} - 1.$ Pay attention to what value of $i$ the summation starts from and hopefully it should make sense.